# Not receiving response from REGISTER request hypereldger

Tags: linux, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to deploy hyerledger fabric using Docker by following the instructions in the hyperledger documentation. Everything seems to work fine up until I run the command to start and register my chaincode:

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 ./chaincode_example02
```

When I run the command from my host machine (an ubuntu 16.04 instance hosted in AWS) I get the following output

[output from start and register command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3wqF.png)

The command hangs indefinitely (I have tried waiting for upwards of ten minutes with no change). The Docker logs show that the request was sent and that the peer attempted to send a response
[output from Docker logs showing that the peer received the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTMkL.png)

So, my question is, why am I not receiving a response from the peer when it is clearly receiving my request?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be the location where the command to register the chaincode was issued.  I understand that the command was run from the host that supports the Docker environment.  I would suggest running the command from within a Docker container for the peer.  There is a [prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437440/hyperledger-using-docker-toolbox/41513435#41513435) that might be helpful.